# How can you represent a .NET DataType in a UML Diagram

Tags: uml, diagramming

I am new to UML diagramming, but I'm trying to learn the ropes.  Using a tool such as Visio or AgroUML how would you represent a .NET Datatype in your diagram?  Two examples that I would like to do:

```
DataTable
List<MyObject>
```

The only method I see right now is creating a class that represents a datatable.  As far as representing collections, I can't find any method to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UML, you should use an [aggregation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/caggreg.html) symbol (the diamond: <>)to represent a collection of objects.  A DataTable would be a class in your diagram.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks!  So is the goal of a UML diagram to be language agnostic?

Comment: @Blake - UML isn't tied to any specific language, though I believe that there are code generators for some languages that can take a diagram and turn it into (basic) code.  I find that I mostly use UML when whiteboarding -- rarely, if ever, do I make these part of my permanent artifacts.  I find as artifacts they are pretty hard to keep up-to-date.  I can always generate a class diagram after the fact if I need to.  I use different mechanisms (stories) to capture interactions.